# Checked null with dateTime in REST API SharePoint

Tags: 2013, filter, sharepoint-server, rest

I want to get all article pages which Article Date is not null. so I have try to do by this way.

```
 var ArticlePageContentTypeID = "0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D";
 var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?&$select=ArticleStartDate&$orderby=ArticleStartDate desc&$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,'" + ArticlePageContentTypeID + "') and ArticleStartDate ne null";
 jQuery.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "GET",
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
   success: function(){},
   error: function(){}

  });
```

but it does not working it. error mention that

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I have try with replacing with empty string but it no luck to be found.

Please help me if you are face this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the REST API does not support OData filters on null date values.

There is [an MSDN forums post with someone having the same issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f20cb779-825f-4261-9623-26551fe5c853/how-to-filter-on-null-dates-via-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint) and a member of the SharePoint team mentions that it is a known issue and they are working on it.

> The current implementation of REST does not support null values for
>   filtering on list item queries. But as this is a desirable feature,
>   there is a bug tracking it and we are discussing on when we add this
>   support.

But you could use a CAML query.

Here I am searching for items in a list called `Test List`, and I am posting the following CAML:

```
<View>
   <Query>
      <Where>
         <IsNull>
            <FieldRef Name='DateCompleted' />
         </IsNull>
      </Where>
   </Query>
</View>
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }, 
    url: 'https://kaucher.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle(\'Test List\')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name=\'DateCompleted\' /></IsNull></Where></Query></View>"}', 
    success: function(data){console.log(data); },
    failure: function(data){console.log(data); } 
});
```

That returned the following from my list:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "3e55bc9c-146b-4319-9627-33338da73bc9",
                    "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-bbf4-99fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.Test_x0020_ListListItem"
                },
                "FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"
                    }
                },
                "RoleAssignments": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/RoleAssignments"
                    }
                },
                "AttachmentFiles": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles"
                    }
                },
                "ContentType": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/ContentType"
                    }
                },
                "FieldValuesAsHtml": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml"
                    }
                },
                "FieldValuesAsText": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsText"
                    }
                },
                "FieldValuesForEdit": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/FieldValuesForEdit"
                    }
                },
                "File": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/File"
                    }
                },
                "Folder": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/Folder"
                    }
                },
                "ParentList": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "https://somedomain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(1)/ParentList"
                    }
                },
                "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 1,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010017F678F8FDCCC8468A19A6A067EFF04D",
                "Title": "Test ITem",
                "Test_x0020_Item": "Enter Choice #1",
                "DueDate": "2014-02-21T00:00:00",
                "DateCompleted": null,
                "ID": 1,
                "Modified": "2014-02-14T19:10:59",
                "Created": "2014-02-14T19:10:59",
                "AuthorId": 12,
                "EditorId": 12,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "e5f4e83e-3bfd-47fe-a5c9-41ef51c71d29"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can filter DateTime based on null values. Check my answer.

Comment: I've added some information regarding this being a bug. It may have been corrected in an update. SP1 might fix this...

Comment: Nearly a year later and post SP1, I still get this error.

Comment: I've struggled with this issue for years, but I'm on SP 2016 (not sure of CU, but it's not the first one) and this has **finally** been addressed on-prem!

Answer (score 8):

You can filter out list items with null columns in SharePoint 2016 (definitely after feature pack 1) using REST.

```
$filter=DateField ne null
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query worked perfectly for me:

```
https://<siteurl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyLibrary')/items?$select=Title&$filter=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Issue ne null
```

Can you check if you are using the exact internal name of the DateTime field? Also for test purposes, can you check without the `startswith` filter in your query?

Comment: Yes. it seem to worked my app on Office 365 site, but when i am moved to On-premise server 2013, I got same error mention on post.

Comment: I recall this being an issue in beta and RTM. Maybe it was fixed with an update?

Comment: Quite Possible.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to filter out null dates with a rest query by filtering on dates greater than 1/1/1900...

```
$filter=DueDate gt datetime'1900-01-01T00:00:00'
```

they may have fixed the null thing on Office365, but my on premises install still has the issue.

Answer (score 2):

"$filter=DueDate gt datetime'1900-01-01T00:00:00'" didnt work for me on-premise. For some reason it gave me just all results.

For textfields this worked for me:
"$filter=SomeTextField gt 0"
This gave me all results where SomeTextField not equals null
But visa versa
"$filter=SomeTextField lt 0"
This gave me no results at all

I have no explanation for this, but you can use "$filter=SomeTextField gt 0" to filter out the null-records on textfields.

Comment: Your answer seems a bit of unexplained, Can you please elaborate with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using OData to get data from project online can use default datetime value to filter for null date in task field.

```
&$filter=BaselineFinish eq datetime'0001-01-01T00:00:00' or BaselineStart eq datetime'0001-01-01T00:00:00'
```

null is not supported in this scenario.