# Querying against a note field with the REST API 2013

Tags: query, rest

I'm getting the error

> The field 'OtherInfo' of type 'Note' cannot be used in the query
>   filter expression

whenever I run a query like this: `http://devServer/majorMatter/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Major%20Matter')/items?$filter=(substringof('restructuring',OtherInfo))`

It seems self-explanatory in that you just can't query note fields, but seems an odd omission and my research suggests you should be able to: 
http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/#columns

If this can't be done, how have other people got round this? I'm sure it is quite a common requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work-around is to use the [Search REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview).

Comment: Thanks Paul. This is definitely the way I should go but the search access point seems to have such a different implementation from the web one (e.g. it returns XML rather than JSON). I'll get to work on it!

Comment: You can pass the Accept header specifying application/json;odata=verbose

Comment: @PaulSchaeflein does CSOM supports querying against Note field?

Comment: Your link points to a different article, probably changed since you posted it. I updated it. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a canonical source for all of the fields that cannot be used in a query filter, but there seem to be a number of such fields.

- [Multivalued Lookups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection4)
- [URL](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/favorites-in-the-cloud-implementing-a-windows-8-search-application-with-an-office-365-backend/)
- And in certain versions of SharePoint 2013 (I ***believe*** pre-SP1) [you could not filter on null date values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/checked-null-with-datetime-in-rest-api-sharepoint/91539#91539). This bug seems to have been fixed, at least in O365.

So it seems like we can add "Note" or Rich Text to this list as well. I suspect the reason is due to performance.

Comment: It seems you're right Robert. Even though performance might be a problem I would have liked to have been the judge of that!