# Can we pass null in $filterby in REST query SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, filter

I am trying to get data from SharePoint list using REST query and filter on some column having null values. But It can't return desired items..

```
 http://<Server>/_api/web/Lists(guid'2B3BD6CD-172B-4320-898F-30BA1DA0928E')/Items?$filter=CustomColumn eq null
```

Comment: Any error are u getting? your query seems okay?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor : no error.. but also returning no data ... "results": []

Comment: For all interest users, It's sad to say that $filter does not support null as value.. and there is one work around is there.. visit this [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/checked-null-with-datetime-in-rest-api-sharepoint?rq=1) to find answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that ODATA for SharePoint REST does not support the filtering based on null.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4690e596-aeae-49e7-9057-f31352d92e07/how-to-filter-on-empty-string-value-list-items-using-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint

But there ist someone with nearly the same issue here:

[Checked null with dateTime in REST API SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/checked-null-with-datetime-in-rest-api-sharepoint?rq=1)

Comment: Yes.. you are right.. your given [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/checked-null-with-datetime-in-rest-api-sharepoint?rq=1) has given me solution.. and it's also true that $filter not support null..

Answer (score 0):

I cracked this awhile ago, and had to jog my memory to remember it again. So I am replying to your question so I can find it next time. To filter by non-nulls, use greater than zero. Yes, that actually works for text fields. I don't think it worked on data fields.

```
?$filter=CustomColumn gt 0
```

I don't think I was able to do the opposite and return only records where the field is null. eq 0 or lt 1 or similar attempts returned no records at all.