# SharePoint REST filter items with multiselect field as null

Tags: rest, filter

I wanted to ignore items which have the multiselect field set to null. I used `ne ''` and `ne null` and none seems to work.

Comment: is it a lookup column? or Choice column?

Comment: Also add the SharePoint version you are using...

Comment: its a choice field @AakashMorya

Answer (score 6):

I guess the REST filter does not support `Null` filtering.

> The current implementation of REST does not support null values for
>   filtering on list item queries. But as this is a desirable feature,
>   there is a bug tracking it and we are discussing on when we add this
>   support.

You can find full description and workaround [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/91539/30145)

Based on the SharePoint version you are using, you can use the things shown in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/91549/30145) answer and read the comments on same answer.

Also,

> Because multi-value
>   lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no
>   way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes
>   element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

I found the reference [Query for multi-value lookup fields and users](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#query-for-multi-value-lookup-fields-and-users)