# Filter null value for SharePoint column using REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to fetch the data based on my "EmpData" list. I am able to get the exact rows for the below Rest API query till I don't include "Null" filtration in my below rest

```
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmpData')/items?$top=50000&$Select=ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ID&$filter=((Country eq 'USA')or(EMPScore eq '500')or(Department eq 'HR')or(TechSkill eq 'CRM')or(State eq 'LA'))and(years eq '27')
```

But I don't get any result when I add the Column "Result ** as (Result eq 'null') to filter null values** with my below Rest API

```
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmpData')/items?$top=6000&$Select=ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ID&$filter=((Country eq 'USA')or(EMPScore eq '500')or(Department eq 'HR')or(TechSkill eq 'CRM')or(State eq 'LA'))and(years eq '27')and(Result eq 'null')"
```

Can any one please do let me what's wrong in above API and what is the exact way of approach to fetch null values fro the column Result **(Result eq 'null')** using Rest

Answer (score 2):

I've read this article you may want to try what he did

[Checked null with dateTime in REST API SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/checked-null-with-datetime-in-rest-api-sharepoint?rq=1)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST", 
headers: { 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }, 
url: 'https://kaucher.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle(\'Test List\')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name=\'DateCompleted\' /></IsNull></Where></Query></View>"}', 
success: function(data){console.log(data); },
failure: function(data){console.log(data); }
```

});

Try using CAML filtering instead

Answer (score 1):

The following code will bring back items if the Result has a space (empty). If nothing is stored in the Result then it is null, and ODATA for SharePoint REST does not support the filtering based on null.

Try below: **Result eq ''**

```
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmpData')/items?$top=6000&$Select=ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ID&$filter=((Country eq 'USA')or(EMPScore eq '500')or(Department eq 'HR')or(TechSkill eq 'CRM')or(State eq 'LA'))and(years eq '27')and(Result eq '')"
```

Use Caml Query on Javascript Object model as a work around.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (december 2021), in SharePoint Online, we can do:

```
"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmpData')/items?$top=10&$Select=ColumnA,ID&$filter=Result eq null"
```

`null` must be in lower case.