# Filtering List Data

Tags: list, sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I have a small requirement where in i want to filter the list data based on some columns but i cannot wrap my head around the Rest Api Query.

So, i want to filter data based on few columns which are

- Should Cost
- Actual Model Start
- SC Start Date

  Now i want to filter data based on if these columns are empty return me the result. I have the query down below please help me on this.

  ```
    /_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items? $select=Project_x0020_Name,Planned_x0020_Completion_x0020_D,Actual_x0020_Completion_x0020_Da,Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$filter=Should-Cost eq '' and Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id"
  ```

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of Should Cost field? Single line of text or number?

Comment: it is Number Field

Answer (score 0):

If you want empty/null value then you can you below query to filter by null.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CountryList')/items?$select=Title, Country&$filter=(Country eq null)
```

So now your query look like below,

```
"{sp Web Url}/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,Planned_x0020_Completion_x0020_D,Actual_x0020_Completion_x0020_Da,Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$filter=Should-Cost eq null and Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id"
```

Answer (score 0):

OData does not support filtering on null values in SharePoint REST GET Method in.

However you can pass CAML query in REST POST Method or you can achieve same using JSOM.

You can find both the examples [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/checked-null-with-datetime-in-rest-api-sharepoint).

Comment: does this answers your question?